# Sandboxes for DE Packaging org?

Tags: sandbox, isv, beta-managed-package, developer-edition

Any chance to get Sandboxes for the DE Packaging org of our managed ISV package?

Besides having short and incremental sprints we also have long running investigations. Those need to work on the latest state of our trunk. But we also  need to keep our trunk releasable so we cannot allow unstable code directly in the DE Packaging org.

I know we could use seperate DE orgs and merge changes back to the PACKAGING org using Ant and other CI tools. But for our situation a Sandbox with change sets would be much leaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe branch orgs might be a solution here.  They are essentially sandboxes of your packaging org that retain the same namespace.  However, you cannot use them to upload new package releases and I have no idea if you can use change sets to transfer changes from a branch org to your packaging org.

As for the CI option, I've spent the last 2 years implementing CI for our projects and can definitely say it's proven well worth the investment (though yes, I am biased).  We've released all the build and automation scripts open source at https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI which should make it pretty easy to set up CI against a managed package development project.